# ImageJ exec, running bash script which executes a python script

Tags: python, exec, sh, imagej

I am trying to execute a bash script from ImageJ (1.51) with following;

```
exec("sh", "/home/user/Documents/list.sh");
```

and script works well, with exception of a single line in it:

```
python2 thescript.py inputfile.txt outputfile.txt
```

This line above appears directly skipped.

I also tried the following command in 'list.sh' as the only line, to see a returning message, nothing come up in log window.

```
/usr/bin/python2 --version
```

Is it due to limitation of exec command in ImageJ scripting? Can you think of any other solutions for this?

(Please see the following link for further details ;
http://forum.imagej.net/t/running-bash-script-from-macro/4819/13)

Regards,

Comment: The same thing is being discussed on [this thread in the ImageJ forum](http://forum.imagej.net/t/running-bash-script-from-macro/4819?u=imagejan). If you cross-post here, please link to the forum (and vice versa), so that others can understand the complete story of your issue.

Comment: Post edited, thanks.